# Linux backup all files with known extensions with timestamps

Tags: linux, shell

I want to backup all files with a given extension in a directory but I want them to be with timestamps.

Given a directory:
Sample/ with multiple subdirectory and a subfolder name BACKUPS.

```
cd Sample
find . -name '*.xml' -exec cp {} BACKUPS \;
```

Say I have multiple xml files in this Sample folder and I want them to be copied to the BACKUPS folder but I want them to be timestamp

say..

```
text.xml.20171107
conf.xml.20171107
```

I am able to backup the files but I could not figure out how to append a timestamp to the files using the find command.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: Ohh sorry..I thought it is okay to ask about shell scripting here.  I am making a bash script on some of my file configurations that are in a linux platform.  So does it mean it is not allowed to ask bash shell scripting here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try this:

```
find . -name '*.xml' -execdir cp {} "$PWD/BACKUPS/{}.$(date +%Y%m%d)" \;
```

As before, we use `find . -name '*.xml'` to locate all the files. However, in order to get rid of the names of subdirectories, we use `-execdir` instead of `exec`. This causes the specified command to be run from inside the subdirectory the current file is in and replaces `{}` by its base name.

This means we have to modify cp's second argument (the target filename). We now pass `"$PWD/BACKUPS"` to create an absolute path (`$PWD` is the current working directory). This way `cp` always targets the right directory, even when invoked from a subdirectory of `Sample`.

Finally, the filename we use is constructed from `{}.$(date +%Y%m%d)`. `$( )` runs the specified command and substitutes its output (the current date, in this case). This is done by the shell before `find` is invoked, so `find` just sees `.../{}.20171107`. The `{}` part is replaced by `find` itself just before it runs each `cp`.

Comment: I am getting cp: cannot create regular file ‘/home/user1/Sample/BACKUPS/./sample.yaml.20171107’: No such file or directory

Comment: @MarkEstrada What does `ls -l /home/user1/Sample/BACKUPS` report?

Comment: sorry..it works... I type smallcap backups... whats the difference between the exec and execdir? Is there any performance hit on this?  Haven't known the execdir so far in my linux reading

Comment: @MarkEstrada As I said, it "*causes the specified command to be run from inside the subdirectory the current file is in*". See https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_mono/find.html#Single-File.

Comment: Oh sorry..I haven't refreshed my browser.. you have answered it already.  My apology.  Thanks.

Comment: Another question please, if I don't backup it in a specified folder and just backup the files to where it is right now.  What should be the proper command?  I tried find . -name '*.xml' -exec cp {}.$(date +%Y%m%d) \; but it seems not to work

Comment: Almost. You need `cp {} {}.$(date +%Y%m%d)`.

Comment: Ohhh...thank you very much.. I learned a lot today about exec.  Cheers!